# How can I use development tools to find css class of a plugin item

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I have this small technical question about using development tools such as firebug or google chrome D.T. in finding css class

that lets say I have a plugin and would like to know a css class to modify it, how can I do that using the Development tools ?

thanks a lot in advance ... and excuse me :) I am little bit newbie :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what kind of plugin you have, but if it is a simple `<div>` in your HTML, just right click on it and select "Inspect Element" (in Chrome with dev tools, there is something similar in Firefox) which will show you the HTML as it is right now even after some JavaScript library might have added some dynamic content. So this will show you also the css class of the elements. On the right, you will also see which parts of CSS are active for this element. That also shows you the css classes (including classes from parent containers).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help !! appreciate it :)